# Why are my divs not moving when I'm pressing .button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bunch of divs that all have gotten the same class 'a'. They all have position:absolute and are placed somewhere on the screen (using css). The divs closest to the left edge should be moved to the left (out of picture), the divs closest to the right edge should be moved to the right and regarding the remaining divs, the top ones move upwards and the rest downwards. I have made a fairly simple code but it doesn't seem to work. Any help would be appreciated but please keep in mind that I'm a beginner so hopefully no extremely complicated solutions.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".button").on("click", function() {
        var name = ('.a');
        for (var i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
            var left = $(name[i]).css("left");
            var top = $(name[i]).css("top")
            if (left <= 30 + '%') {
                $(name[i]).animate({
                    left: left - 50 + '%',
                }, "slow")
            } else if (left >= 70 + '%') {
                $(name[i]).animate({
                    left: left + 50 + '%',
                }, "slow")
            } else if (top <= 50 + '%') {
                $(name[i]).animate({
                    top: top - 50 + '%',
                }, "slow")
            } else {
                $(name[i]).animate({
                    top: top + 50 + '%',
                }, "slow")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide the HTML associated with this jQuery listener ?

Comment: Why are you testing with `+ '%'` in your `if` statements? You’re comparing strings lexicographically instead of numbers. Also, you mean `$('.a')` instead of `('.a')`.

Comment: Browser is not going to return your positions in percentage, regardless of how they were set in style. They will be returned in pixels and you need to calculate percentage yourself

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you are a bit confused about iterating elements.
Try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".button").on("click", function() {

        $(".a").each(function () {
            var left = $(this).position().left;
            var top = $(this).position().top;
            if (left <= screen.width * 0.3) {
                $(this).animate({
                    left: left - 50 + 'px',
                }, "slow")
            } else if (left >= screen.width * 0.7) {
                $(this).animate({
                    left: left + 50 + 'px',
                }, "slow")
            } else if (top <= screen.height * 0.5) {
                $(this).animate({
                    top: top - 50 + 'px',
                }, "slow")
            } else {
                $(this).animate({
                    top: top + 50 + 'px',
                }, "slow")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I switched the '%' to 'px' and changed '.css("left");' to '.position().left;' but other than that your code was a big help! I will make sure to use 'this' and '.each' more frequently in the future. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you @Krugg for accepting my answer. I was so surprised about iteration I didn't notice other stuffs. I am going to edit to improve it.